# Wix MSI Project Harvesting Error Message 'dll is not running' on Build

Tags: visual-studio, dll, wix4

I have a Wix MSI project and all I am currently trying to do is harvest the output files of my project but I am getting this error message.

[image: Wix Build Error Message]

The project still builds and harvests all of the files successfully.

The culprit dll is 32 bits, while the rest of the dlls are 64 bit. The project build is set to 64 bit.

I would like the project to build, harvest of of the files into an MSI, while not showing any error messages.